# HazelcastInstance not invoked using Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hazelcast

I am trying to use embedded Hazelcast in Spring MVC REST application. My pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.rajib.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>rest</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rest Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>rest</finalName>
</build>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <springframework.version>4.3.17.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springframework.security.version>4.2.6.RELEASE</springframework.security.version>
    <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>
</properties>
```

My Spring configuration class for Hazelcast Instance (server):

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class HazelcastConfig {
    @Bean
    public Config config() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("127.0.0.1:5701");
        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(final Config config) {
        return Hazelcast.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
}
```

And my Spring configuration for Hazelcast client:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("127.0.0.1:5701");
        HazelcastInstance hInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(hInstance);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I start this Sping MVC app, getting following error:

```
May 31, 2018 9:24:39 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Registering annotated classes: [class com.rajib.rest.ApplicationConfiguration]
May 31, 2018 9:24:41 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.6] HazelcastClient 3.8.6 (20170921 - b1aa90b) is STARTING
May 31, 2018 9:24:41 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.6] HazelcastClient 3.8.6 (20170921 - b1aa90b) is STARTED
May 31, 2018 9:24:41 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.6] Trying to connect to [127.0.0.1]:5701 as owner member
May 31, 2018 9:24:42 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
WARNING: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.6] Exception during initial connection to [127.0.0.1]:5701, exception com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
May 31, 2018 9:24:42 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
WARNING: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.6] Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 1970 ms later, attempt 1 of 2.
May 31, 2018 9:24:44 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.6] Trying to connect to [127.0.0.1]:5701 as owner member
May 31, 2018 9:24:45 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
WARNING: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.6] Exception during initial connection to [127.0.0.1]:5701, exception com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
May 31, 2018 9:24:45 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
WARNING: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.6] Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 1981 ms later, attempt 2 of 2.
May 31, 2018 9:24:47 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.6] HazelcastClient 3.8.6 (20170921 - b1aa90b) is SHUTTING_DOWN
May 31, 2018 9:24:47 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.6] HazelcastClient 3.8.6 (20170921 - b1aa90b) is SHUTDOWN
May 31, 2018 9:24:47 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [com/rajib/security/CachingConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'cacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: [[127.0.0.1]:5701]
May 31, 2018 9:24:47 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [com/rajib/security/CachingConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'cacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: [[127.0.0.1]:5701]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5041)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [com/rajib/security/CachingConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'cacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: [[127.0.0.1]:5701]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [com/rajib/security/CachingConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'cacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: [[127.0.0.1]:5701]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:389)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at com.rajib.security.CachingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80ae90a8.cacheManager(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.AbstractCachingConfiguration.useCachingConfigurer(AbstractCachingConfiguration.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.AbstractCachingConfiguration.setConfigurers(AbstractCachingConfiguration.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:701)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1272)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'cacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: [[127.0.0.1]:5701]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried: [[127.0.0.1]:5701]
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport.connectToCluster(ClusterListenerSupport.java:178)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientClusterServiceImpl.start(ClientClusterServiceImpl.java:189)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.start(HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.java:404)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientManager.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClientManager.java:78)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:72)
    at com.rajib.security.CachingConfiguration.cacheManager(CachingConfiguration.java:24)
    at com.rajib.security.CachingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80ae90a8.CGLIB$cacheManager$0(<generated>)
    at com.rajib.security.CachingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80ae90a8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$48c056c5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.rajib.security.CachingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80ae90a8.cacheManager(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 87 more
```

As you can see, Hazelcast client is getting triggered, but Hazelcast server is not invoked at all. So hazelcast client gives error saying it is not able to connect. Am I doing anything wrong with Spring configuration?

Answer (score 1):

When you are embedding hazelcast , you do not need to run a seperate Hazelcast Client in the same JVM. When the program starts what guarentee do you have that hazelcast server starts up before Hazelcastclient ?
Looking at you logs Hazelcast client is started by the spring framework and it cannot locate hazelcast server.

**You have 2 options**

1. Run a remote hazelcast server  and let Hazelcastclient embedded in
   your MVC to connect to it.
2. Run hazelcast server only embedded in
   your MVC application

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious you misconfigured hazelcast when looking at the exception. Is any hazelcast instance already running at 127.0.0.1:5701 ? I would suggest to read hazelcast documentation to find out how to properly configure it depending on your needs.

By the way, you have use the HazelcastInstance as both the client and the server if you embed hazelcast in your application. client is only needed when you connect to an external hazelcast cluster.

Comment: I am doing Hazelcast.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(config); for 127.0.0.1:5701. So I am creating a Hazelcast server member. But the problem was, this bean was not getting invoked. Now I have fixed that configuration issue. Now it is working fine.

Comment: I still have one question: in your example, you have used following config:     @Bean
  Config config(
    final MembershipListener listener,
    @Value("${clustering.hazelcast.members:127.0.0.1}") final String members) throws UnknownHostException { }                                                           From where will we get MembershipListener listener? How did you configure the MembershipListener listener?

Comment: You don't necessarly need one. We have one for our own needs (managing cluster quorum and master node based on members of the cluster) because we have batch jobs who must only run on master (and when quorum is ok).

Comment: We will also run in WebSphere cluster (multiple nodes). So this application will be installed in multiple nodes in a WebSphere cluster. Since we have Hazelcast server embedded in this app, then multiple Hazelcast server members will be created (if I am not wrong). So we need to take care of clustering for Hazelcast server member - right?

Comment: It depends if you need to elect a master node and make sure your cluster meets the quorum to avoid common issues like split brain. Clustering is more difficult than it seems. It makes emerge a lot of new issues related to having multiples machines talking together.

Comment: Can you share how did you configure the MembershipListener listener?

Comment: Why do you need it? It's specific to our own application.

Comment: You're trying to start a Hazelcast Server and a Hazelcast Client in the same process ? If so why do you want a Hazelcast Client ?